# Rule notes are lost when a rule is deactivated

Tags: sonarqube

Before deactivating a rule, I would like to add a note why I'm deactivating it, to have a record for the future about the reason for deactivating.

So far so good, I can add a note, but once I deactivate the rule, the notes on it are deleted.

The workaround at the moment is to "add a note" by extending the rule description, which isn't really what mean to do.

I believe the notes should be kept, regardless of the activation. If this isn't a bug, please consider implementing it as an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

We're not going in that direction. See https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5064

Comment: I respectfully disagree."it does not play well with notes on inactive/deactivated rules" that is an implementation problem not a concept problem. "Wjat's more, this feature is not widely used", very questionable statement, do you collect usage information? I recall at least 3 issues in the past requesting this functionality.